# Get formated order date plus 5 days in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce, orders

Im fetching the order date on the Order Received page (Thank you). For estimation delivery date I need to add 5 days to this date to output it on this page.

Please any one suggest in PHP we can use **`strtotime()`** function, to achieve that?

But it's not working for me.

My Code to fetching order is **`<?php echo $order->order_date; ?>`**

I need a date with **`<?php echo $order->order_date; ?>`+5 days date** in WooCommerce.

Comment: what format <?php echo $order->order_date; ?> is getting printed ?

Answer (score 1):

To get the **order date + 5 days** using [**`date()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [**`strtotime()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) PHP functions, your code is going to be:

```
<?php 
    // The orders date
    $order_date = $order->get_date_created();
    $order_date = $order_date->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    // The order date + 5 days
    $order_date_5d = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $order_date . ' +5 days' );
    
    // TESTING OUTPUT
    echo 'ORDER DATE: ' . $order_date . '<br>';
    echo 'ORDER DATE + 5 days: '.$order_date_5d . '<br>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php echo $date_i18n( wc_date_format(), strtotime( $order->order_date ) + 5 * DAY_IN_SECONDS ); ?>
```